# guess timezone name using javascript

Tags: javascript, moment-timezone, dayjs

I'm working on React app, I want to detect timezone like this format "Africa/Bangui", but it return it as 'Etc/GMT-1', I know it's my machine problem, since I tried the other browsers.

I tried:

- Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
- dayjs guess
- moment guess

all return the some format: "Etc/GMT-1"
How can fix this, and take i consideration other clients that have the problem (in their system)
I want always this format "Africa/Bangui"

Comment: Isn't the CAR in GMT **+** 1?

Comment: The problem is that whatever the offset to GMT/UTC it will be likely be shared by multiple different timezones. What do you need the timezone for? Perhaps there's another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: It sounds like your machine is set to `Etc/GMT-1` (i.e., a fixed offset of UTC+01:00).  You haven't told us anything else about your machine, such as operating system, time zone settings, etc. - so it's difficult to suggest any specific solution other than you should investigate how to change the time zone setting for your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

use moment timezone
https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

```
moment.tz.guess(); // America/Chicago
// suppose the client's timezone changes to Europe/Berlin
moment.tz.guess(); // America/Chicago
moment.tz.guess(true); // Europe/Berlin
moment.tz.guess(); // Europe/Berlin
```

Comment: I tried all those, it return this format "Etc/GMT-1", in other computer it's correct, seems it's my machine problem, is there a way to get over this and return the correct format

Comment: [MomentJS is not receommended for new development](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US');
const resolvedOptions = dateTimeFormat.resolvedOptions();
const timeZone = resolvedOptions.timeZone;

console.log(timeZone); // 'Asia/Calcutta'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: your exact code return "Etc/GMT-1" on y machine, I want this format pattern : "America/Chicago" region/city

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).